# Best way to Convert HTML Button to a Link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

I have the following code where I have a Button that has the arrow hack.  The only issue is I'd like to have this display the link on the status bar.  A button does not achieve. How do I convert this to a a href link and still be able to keep that arrow?   Here is my code:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/60n0ruyj/1)

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-default my-button my-button-active">My Button</button>
```

CSS:

```
.my-button {
    color: #fff ;
    background-color: #444346;
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    border:none;
    margin-right:20px;
    position: relative;
    outline:0;
    width:31%;
}


.my-button-active:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 7px #444346;
    border-left: solid 7px transparent;
    border-right: solid 7px transparent;
}

.my-button-active:hover:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 7px #e6e6e6;
    border-left: solid 7px transparent;
    border-right: solid 7px transparent;
}
```

Comment: This one http://jsfiddle.net/samirkumardas/60n0ruyj/2/

Comment: The CSS is all screwy (I'm sure you can figure that part out), but `<button><a></a></button>` works. http://jsfiddle.net/60n0ruyj/3/

Comment: @Samir  Post your answer below and I'll accept. That was perfect.

Comment: At last! Some one who understands that links should be links even if they *look* like buttons. [Links are not buttons](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: @KingKongFrog  answer added :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple. Just convert the button to a and add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`  to the class .my-button.

Fiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/samirkumardas/60n0ruyj/2/

Answer (score 1):

Change your html to an anchor tag:

```
<a class="btn-lg btn-default my-button my-button-active" href="">My Button that links to some other page</a>
```

Replace your `.my-button` selector with:

```
.my-button {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #444346;
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    outline: 0;
    width: 31%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your button to an anchor and adjust your css.

```css
div {
  margin: 30px;
  
}

a.my-button {
  color: #fff ;
  background-color: #444346;
  font-size:15px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border:none;
  margin-right:20px;
  position: relative;
  outline:0;
  width:31%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


.my-button-active:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 7px #444346;
  border-left: solid 7px transparent;
  border-right: solid 7px transparent;
}

.my-button-active:hover:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 7px #e6e6e6;
  border-left: solid 7px transparent;
  border-right: solid 7px transparent;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <a href="#" type="button" class="btn-lg btn-default my-button my-button-active">My Button that links to some other page</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This displays differently than the original, because you forgot to add a  few things to the css.  Not a complete solution.

Comment: @Sean Stopnik Could help me out here and tell me what is missing, because to me it looks exactly the same, viewing this in chrome and firefox.

Comment: See my answer to the issue.

Comment: @SeanStopnik But the default display behavior of a button is not block, it is inline-block.

Comment: The issue was to replace the button tag with an anchor tag, and make it display the same.  An anchor tag is an inline element.  We have to add display: block to the anchor tag to give it positioning.  We then need to add text-align: center to get it to display the same as the original.

Comment: I agree with you on the text centering, i actually forgot that part. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

After changing your `<button>` tag to an `<a>` tag, the key thing is to have `display: block;` applied to it, as `<a>` tags are primarily inline elements and cannot have padding and margin.

Comment: @Paulie_D what I meant was, to change the `<button>` tag to `<a>` tag and use that CSS on it. I assumed the OP's intention was already to change the tag.

Comment: Then you should have made that statement in the answer. Other users would not know that you have made that assumption and you can't know the mind of the OP.

Comment: @Paulie_D well the OP did ask about changing it to an `<a>` tag. I'll edit my answer